# Simple CSS Nested Divs issue

Tags: css, html

I'm clearly losing the plot... I just can't seem to figure this one out!

Ok so this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFwTq/) has 2 `divs` - one inside the other.

I want the blue one to always be 100% wide, regardless of how wide the window has been reduced.

If you load it up and then reduce the width of the result view to smaller than the red block you will see that a scroll bar at the bottom appears - scroll this to the right and the blue block is now not at 100% of the window - well, it is at 100% of the new size, but i need it to be blue all the way across.

This same effect will be used in a footer too. Essentially header/content/footer will have a max of 1080px and the background divs for the header and footer will have an image which is to stretch the whole way across. - there will eventually be a layout-footer and footer div using the same methods.

Any idea how I can achieve this? I'm having a huge brain-fart...

Comment: have you tried `min-width:100%;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

```
#layout-header { min-width: 600px; }
```

Comment: Ya bugger! I KNEW it was something simple! Excellent, many thanks :) I can get back to the actual backend coding now :D

Comment: This only works if you know exactly what size everything inside it will be and it never changes.  As soon as the red box or something else inside becomes bigger or smaller than 600px you end up with the same problem again.

Comment: That's ok as in this solution the red box will always be 1080px fixed size. the contents of the red box will never go above 1080 either.

Answer (score 0):

Try using css attribute overflow for your header.  I'm not exactly sure if this is what were you were looking for, but this will make the blue box contain a scrollbar inside it if the red box is bigger.

```
#layout-header
{
    width:100%;
    height:126px;
    background-color:blue;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: no, not quite - that gives me a scroll bar right beneath the blue block. Essentially I want that blue block to maintain 100% width - i'm sure this should be simple, though it's eluding me at the mo..

Comment: so basically, you want the blue box to always size to fit the contents inside it?

Comment: no - in this case i want the blue box to always be full width of the browser.

Comment: Essentially that blue box will have a background that the navigation sits on - that background must go full width of the browser, even if he user reduced the width smaller than the 1080px red box - that red box won't be shrinking.